# I am getting illegal start of expression

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

//trying to print pyramid shape
class try    
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
          Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Enter the number of lines:");
          int n=in.nextInt();
          for(int i=n;i>0;i--)
          {
            for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            j=n-(i-1);
            for(int k=0;k<j;k++)
            {
                System.out.print(j+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
          }
        }
}
```

But iam not able to print solve.

Comment: It has compilation issue !! move the `j` inside to for loop

Comment: The compiler will tell you the offending line. Tell us about it.

Answer (score 3):

`try` is a reserved keyword in Java. You cannot use it as a class name. Simply rename your class - i.e. to `MyTry`

Reference: [Java Language Keywords](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html)

Answer (score 0):

`try` is a [key word](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) you have to change your class name first. (Use `MyClass`)

How you can do this, You have to define and initialize the variable before use them.

```
 for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
      System.out.print(" "); // j visible inside for loop only
    }
 j=n-(i-1); // access j from outside for-loop is not possible
```

You can make this mistake correct by your own. Don't you use an `IDE` for coding?

Comment: thank u..nd plz tell me how to use IDE for coding sir.!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution of your problem.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

//trying to print pyramid shape
class Try    
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
          Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Enter the number of lines:");
          int n=in.nextInt();
          int i,j;
          for(i=n;i>0;i--)
          {
            for( j=1;j<=i;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            j=n-(i-1);
            for(int k=0;k<j;k++)
            {
                System.out.print(j+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
          }
        }
}
```